# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin^2x}{2x^2}}$ without L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have been trying to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin^2x}{2x^2}}$$
Finally, I used the L'Hospital's Theorem and I got the answer $1/2$, but I wonder if there is a way to solve this without this. 
I also tried using Squeeze Theorem, but my boundaries were approaching different numbers.

Comment: If you know that $\sin x / x \to 1$, this is one line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know this. Should I have known it?

Comment: Well, since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the definition of the derivative of $\sin$ at $0$, yes.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: There is an answer providing the most elementary method. Make sure you upvote it if useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$\sin^\prime = \cos$, so that $\sin^\prime(0) = \cos 0 = 1.$ Can you make this quantity appear?

**In more detail:** *(place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents)*

> You can write$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} = \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}\right)^2 \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \left(\sin^\prime(0)\right)^2 = 1$$using continuity of the function $t\mapsto t^2$.

Comment: This is circular reasoning, because the proof of $\sin' x=\cos x$ usually uses the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) there are some proofs of why $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: Depends on the proof. Yours, maybe -- some use the fact that $\sin x = \mathrm{Im}(e^{ix})$ and differentiate the complex function; some use the series representation; some use other techniques (e.g., based on $\cos^2 + \sin^2 =1$)... Whether something is "legitimate" or not is really a matter of background.

Comment: @ClementC. i think limit is a more low level concept, so it should'nt be proven using derivatives. please correct me if you think i am wrong

Comment: It may be - that's for the OP to judge... here is a simple method, only requiring knowledge of derivative of sine (which I would deem basic in almost all context not specifying "from first principles"). Whether it is allowed in the context of the OP's question is up to him/her.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you want to use the Squeeze Theorem, you can proceed geometrically and observe that for $x\neq 0$ \begin{align}\frac12|\sin x| \le \frac12|x|\le \frac12|\tan x| &\implies 1\le \frac{|x|}{|\sin x|}\le \frac{1}{|\cos x|}\\ &\implies |\cos x|\le \frac{|\sin x|}{|x|}\le 1\\&\implies\cos^2x\le \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\le1\end{align}

Comment: This geometric interpretation pre-supposes that you have chosen a scale for the angle that already satisfies this inequality resp. has the limit as 1. Remember, geometrically the angle is an equivalence class of ordered pairs of intersecting lines.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0}\Bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigg)^2=\frac{1}{2}$